# How to get visitor browser type and OS on apache

Tags: c#, asp.net, ubuntu, mono, apache2

So, I have a basic LAMP server that I use to run my asp.net websites (running mono). When the user accesses my website, I record all of their information in my database.

When testing the application from code, it works like a charm.  However, if I publish my website to my server and access the website, it records nothing.

My desktop runs Win7 and the server is Ubuntu 64bit w/ Apache2. My first thought was maybe I wasn't doing it right. So, I ran the code from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx and everything was false. I'm lead to believe that the issue isn't necessarily my code but possibly with apache2.

From what you can see, I do code around this a little.

```
 public string GetBrowserType()
    {
        var value = String.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type != "*0")
        {
            value = bc.Type;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public string GetBrowserName()
    {
        var value = String.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser != "*")
        {
            value = bc.Browser;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public string GetOs()
    {
        var value = String.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Platform != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Platform != "unknown")
        {
            value = bc.Platform;
            //value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Platform;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

So would the issue be with Apache? Is there a mod that I need to enable to allow it to log everything?

Comment: probably you do not have update/install the browser database on the asp.net running pool.

Comment: What browser database are you referring to?

Comment: to make Request.Browser works you must have configure the files that exist on \Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers\

Comment: Awesome. This appears to have gotten it to work. Thanks

Comment: So I place it as answer since no other have say anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have not update/install the browser detection files on the asp.net running pool.

to make Request.Browser works you must have configure the files on `\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers\`